# Music on iPhone not showing up in iTunes on macOS

Tags: iphone, itunes, mojave, apple-music, itunes-match

If I connect my iPhone to my Mac via USB cable, iTunes launches and shows the iPhone icon in the toolbar. But if I click that, no content whatsoever is displayed under the "On My Device" header (except one iBook I bought).

Does anyone know how to solve this? I would like to manage the music downloaded to my iPhone via macOS iTunes, as removing downloaded music on the iPhone itself is a disaster in user friendliness.

I have iTunes Match, Apple Music and running macOS Mojave 10.14.5 with iOS 12.3.1.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps below to fix the problem of Apple Music not showing up in iTunes on Mac

1. Open iTunes on your Mac by clicking on the iTunes icon in the Dock of your Mac.

iTunes Icon in the Dock of Mac

2. Next, click on iTunes tab in the top Menu Bar of your Mac and then click on Preferences… option in the drop-down menu (See image below)

iTunes Preferences Option on Mac

3. On the Preferences screen, click on the General tab (in case it is not already selected) and then check the little box next to Show Apple Music Features and click on the OK button to save your preferences for iTunes.

Show Apple Music Features on Mac

4. In case “Show Apple Music Features” is already selected and Apple Music is not showing in iTunes, Uncheck the box and then click OK.

Do Not Show Apple Music Features on Mac

5. Next, click on iTunes tab in the top Menu Bar of your Mac and then click on Preferences… option in the drop-down menu.

iTunes Preferences Option on Mac

6. On the Preferences screen, click on the General tab, check the box for Show Apple Music Features. and click on OK.

Show Apple Music Features on Mac

Steps 4, 5 and 6 are applicable in case a software glitch or iTunes bug was preventing Apple Music from appearing in iTunes on your Mac.

Comment: Hi Julia, thanks for your elaborate answer. However, there is no option "Show Apple Music Features" (iTunes 12.9.5.5).

Answer (score 0):

The music available on the iPhone is not shown in the iTunes when you click on the iPhone icon in the iTunes toolbar.

The music should be present in your iTunes library (if you originally synced it from iTunes to your iPhone). This is by design and how syncing music from iTunes to iPhone works.

You need to connect your iPhone to the computer with iTunes where from you originally synced your iPhone. Once connected, go to music sync section within iPhone section under iTunes and check/uncheck to add/remove songs.

Comment: Thanks. The computer where from I originally synced my iPhone is long gone. Is there a procedure to make my current computer the one with which I can add/remove songs?

Comment: @RichardKranendonk As mentioned, you have an [iTunes Match](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204146) subscription. You should be able to turn on [iCloud Music Library](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204926) and download music onto your desktop. Thereafter, you can selectively sync music from the comfort of iTunes.

Comment: The problem I'm trying to solve is deleting lots of downloaded music that is now on my iPhone.